# Combine these two mySQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, group-concat

**This query produces the right answer:**

```
SELECT users.*,
        SUM(overtime_list.shift_length) AS overtime_total,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(users_roles.role_ID) FROM users_roles WHERE users.user_ID = users_roles.user_ID) AS roles
    FROM availability_list
    INNER JOIN users
        ON users.user_ID = availability_list.user_ID
    INNER JOIN stations
        ON users.station_ID = stations.station_ID
    INNER JOIN overtime_list
        ON overtime_list.user_ID = users.user_ID
        AND overtime_list.date >= '$totalovertimedays'
    WHERE availability_list.date = '$date'
    AND availability_list.type = '$type'
    GROUP BY users.user_ID
    ORDER BY overtime_total ASC
```

**output:**

```
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |  user_ID | user    |   roles                    |  overtime_total  |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        1 |   Smith |    1,2                     |        12        |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        2 |   Jones |    1,2,3                   |        7         |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
```

**This is the desired result:**

```
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |  user_ID | user    |   roles                    |  overtime_total  |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        1 |   Smith |    Admin, Staff            |        12        |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
 |        2 |   Jones |    Admin, Staff, Other     |        7         |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
```

**This is a join I can use, which seems to allow the group_concat to correct join "admin, staff, other" - but I cant work out how to incorporate it into the main query above?**

```
SELECT users.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(roles.short_name  separator ', ') roles
FROM users
JOIN users_roles ON users.user_ID = users_roles.user_ID
JOIN roles ON users_roles.role_ID= users_roles.role_ID
GROUP BY users.user_ID
```

**The users_roles table:**

```
+----------+---------+
|  user_ID | role_ID |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |   1     |
+----------+---------+
|        2 |   1     |
+----------+---------+
|        2 |   2     |
+----------+---------+
|        2 |   3     |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |   3     |
+----------+---------+
```

**The roles table:**

```
+----------+------------+
|  role_ID | short_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 |   Admin    |
+----------+------------+
|        2 |   Super    |
+----------+------------+
|        3 |   Other    |
+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT users.*,
        SUM(overtime_list.shift_length) AS overtime_total,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(roles.short_name) FROM users_roles 
         INNER JOIN roles ON user_roles.role_ID = roles.role_ID
         WHERE users.user_ID = users_roles.user_ID) AS roles
    FROM availability_list
    INNER JOIN users
        ON users.user_ID = availability_list.user_ID
    INNER JOIN stations
        ON users.station_ID = stations.station_ID
    INNER JOIN overtime_list
        ON overtime_list.user_ID = users.user_ID
        AND overtime_list.date >= '$totalovertimedays'
    WHERE availability_list.date = '$date'
    AND availability_list.type = '$type'
    GROUP BY users.user_ID
    ORDER BY overtime_total ASC
```

Comment: Hi Marco - it doesnt work? "Unknown column 'user_roles.role_ID' in 'on clause'"?  The answer above "does work", but it is really slow for some reason - I'm trying to get yours to work...

Comment: @Laurencei Change it to users_roles.role_id.

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you both!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! +rep if I could!!!!!!!!!!!!! Saved me so much headache!

Answer (score 2):

Add derived table and join it back to users. Derived table is used because of aggregate function on overtime_list so data does not become duplicated.

```
SELECT users.*,
    SUM(overtime_list.shift_length) AS overtime_total,
    roles.roles
FROM availability_list
INNER JOIN users
    ON users.user_ID = availability_list.user_ID
INNER JOIN stations
    ON users.station_ID = stations.station_ID
INNER JOIN overtime_list
    ON overtime_list.user_ID = users.user_ID
    AND overtime_list.date >= '$totalovertimedays'
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT users_roles.user_ID, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(roles.short_name  separator ', ') roles
     from users_roles
      INNER JOIN roles ON users_roles.role_ID = roles.role_ID
    group by users_roles.user_ID
) roles
  ON users.user_ID = roles.user_ID
WHERE availability_list.date = '$date'
AND availability_list.type = '$type'
GROUP BY users.user_ID
ORDER BY overtime_total ASC
```

Comment: I think you're missing the roles table in the from clause of the subselect.

Comment: No problem. I like this query because it prevents the select list from getting too long.

Comment: Thanks - this one works - unfortunately it is a slow query (because of the amount of joins I need to do)... but at least I can look into it now. Thanks very much

Comment: Make sure you have up-to-date indexes on all the joined columns.

Comment: the query goes from 0.3 secs (in my original question) to 22secs with the answer here. Is it because the user_roles table has no index? it is unique as a combination of the user_ID + role_ID?

Comment: I believe that an index on user_id in users_roles is mandatory. Unique index on proposed columns would certainly help a lot. But if it is not working out as expected, try @Marco's answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT users.*,
        SUM(overtime_list.shift_length) AS overtime_total,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(users_roles.short_name) FROM users_roles WHERE users.user_ID = users_roles.user_ID) AS roles
    FROM availability_list
    INNER JOIN users
        ON users.user_ID = availability_list.user_ID
    INNER JOIN stations
        ON users.station_ID = stations.station_ID
    INNER JOIN overtime_list
        ON overtime_list.user_ID = users.user_ID
        AND overtime_list.date >= '$totalovertimedays'
    WHERE availability_list.date = '$date'
    AND availability_list.type = '$type'
    GROUP BY users.user_ID
    ORDER BY overtime_total ASC
```

Comment: I get an error that "users_roles.short_name" is an unknown column. I've editted my original question with the users_roles table and the roles table to clarify. Somehow I need to join those two tables BEFORE the CONCAT occurs...?

Answer (score 0):

I never like to employ user functions on queries as database engine treats functions as blackboxes and cant optimize queries inside, so avoid them as possible. With cross apply you get same result as intendend: (didn't test all query as i dont have all objects used)

```
SELECT users.*, 
        SUM(overtime_list.shift_length) AS overtime_total, 
        LEFT(ISNULL(roles.roles, ', '), LEN(ISNULL(roles.roles, ', ')) - 1) as roles 
    FROM availability_list 
    INNER JOIN users 
        ON users.user_ID = availability_list.user_ID 
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT short_name + ', '
        FROM roles 
        inner users_roles ON roles.role_id = users_roles.role_ID 
        WHERE users.user_ID = users_roles.user_ID 
        ORDER BY roles.role_id
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) roles (roles)         
    INNER JOIN stations 
        ON users.station_ID = stations.station_ID 
    INNER JOIN overtime_list 
        ON overtime_list.user_ID = users.user_ID 
        AND overtime_list.date >= '$totalovertimedays' 
    WHERE availability_list.date = '$date' 
    AND availability_list.type = '$type' 
    GROUP BY users.user_ID 
    ORDER BY overtime_total ASC
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is built-in aggregate function in MySql.